# intersectsNode not working?

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm trying to detect when one node overlaps another. I am teaching myself sprite kit and cannot get intersectsNodes to give any output. I've loaded 2 nodes that can be moved around on the screen and then added intersectsNodes in the update section.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
SKSpriteNode* playerShip1;
SKSpriteNode* playerShip2;

if ([playerShip1 intersectsNode: playerShip2]) {
            NSLog(@"your ships overlap");

  }
```

Any thoughts on why no intersection is found?

here is the whole m file.

```
#import "MyScene.h"

 @implementation MyScene

 -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
 if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
      SKSpriteNode* playerShip1 = [SKSpriteNode   spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
      playerShip1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,  playerShip1.frame.size.height);
      playerShip1.name = @"PLAYER_SHIP_1";
      [self addChild:playerShip1];

      SKSpriteNode* playerShip2 = [SKSpriteNode  spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
      playerShip2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,  self.frame.size.height-playerShip2.frame.size.height);
      playerShip2.name = @"PLAYER_SHIP_2";
       [self addChild:playerShip2];


       SKSpriteNode* playerShip3 = [SKSpriteNode    spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
       playerShip3.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,  self.frame.size.height/2);
       playerShip3.name = @"PLAYER_SHIP_3";
       [self addChild:playerShip3];

       activeDragNode = nil;
}
   return self;
}

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    // Identify where this touch is on the scene
   CGPoint scenePosition = [touch locationInNode:self];
   // Find the child node that contains this touch
    SKNode* checkNode = [self nodeAtPoint:scenePosition];
   // Make sure it is a player ship and not another node like the parent SKScene
    if (checkNode && [checkNode.name hasPrefix:@"PLAYER_SHIP"]) {
      activeDragNode = (SKSpriteNode*)checkNode;
      SKAction *zoomAction = [SKAction scaleTo:1.5 duration:.2];
      [checkNode runAction:zoomAction];
      //NSLog(@"your ship has been hit!");

    }
 }

  -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  // Remove reference to which object we are dragging
  activeDragNode=nil;
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint scenePosition = [touch locationInNode:self];
  SKNode* checkNode = [self nodeAtPoint:scenePosition];
  SKAction *shrinkAction = [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:.2];
  [checkNode runAction:shrinkAction];

  }
   - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   // Be sure we have a reference to an object to drag
   if (activeDragNode==nil) return;
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint scenePosition = [touch locationInNode:self];
   CGPoint lastPosition = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];


   // Calculate the new location of the dragged node
    CGPoint newLoc = CGPointMake(activeDragNode.position.x + (scenePosition.x     - lastPosition.x), activeDragNode.position.y + (scenePosition.y -       lastPosition.y));
     // Update this location
      activeDragNode.position = newLoc;
    }
   -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
  SKSpriteNode* playerShip1;
  SKSpriteNode* playerShip2;

  if ([playerShip1 intersectsNode: playerShip2]) {
            NSLog(@"your ships overlap");

    }
      /* Called before each frame is rendered */
     }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set a position for each node:

```
playerShip1.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
```

Second you need to add each node to the view:

```
[self addChild:playerShip1];
```

Also, you are adding the nodes in your update method which is the wrong place. As your code is now, you will continuously add each node 60 times a second.

---

I see you adding additional code. You are creating 3 SKSpriteNodes in your init method which is fine and works. However, you are not keeping a reference to these 3 nodes. This means once they are created, you have no way to access them again. To resolve this, you should create 3 SKSpriteNode class properties or add all 3 nodes into an array (class property for the array). If you don't know what I mean, that's ok, it just means you have a ways to learn.

I suggest you do a couple of tutorials as this will teach some additional fundamentals and prevent a ton of "why isn't this working" frustration in the future.

Comment: Hi, I do add the nodes at the beginning. The only reason I call them again is I get the "undeclared Identifier" error. I'll add the whole m file. It was based on a tutorial which I was adding to.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did see someone do it in an array and another without. Perhaps the other had the SKSpriteNode class properties. I'll do more research. thx